# Javascript methods and variables(beginner)

Tags: javascript

I have a serious problem understanding the code.

```
function replace(str, before, after) {

    var rtt = before;
    var rt;

    if(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase()) {
        var aa = after.split("");
        var u = after[0].toUpperCase();
        aa.splice(0,1,u);
        rt =  aa.join("");    
    }
    else {
       rt = after;
    }

    var r = str.split(" ");  
    var i = r.indexOf(rtt);
    r.splice(i,1, rt);
    var join = r.join(" ");
    return join;
}

replace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

I don't understand why I can't just do `r.join(" ")` after `r.splice(i,1,rt)` and then return `r`? **Why I must declare new variable join?** otherwise return will not return correct statement. The code is correct though.

Comment: You could just do `r = r.join(" ");` instead other than a new variable. But `r.join(" ")` will return a value and not set it, so that's why.

Comment: You can just do `r.splice(i,1, rt); return r.join(" ");`.

Comment: I think I know what is a problem. I thought that join method is similar to array mutators, and that it will modify existing array, but it is wrong. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.

What this method returns ?

> **An array containing the deleted elements.** If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

As far as this question

> Why I must declare new variable join ?

Actually, you don't have to declare a new variable. You can just return this value

```
return r.join(" ");
```

```js
function replace(str, before, after) {

    var rtt = before;
    var rt;

    if(before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase()) {
        var aa = after.split("");
        var u = after[0].toUpperCase();
        aa.splice(0,1,u);
        rt =  aa.join("");    
    }
    else {
       rt = after;
    }

    var r = str.split(" ");  
    var i = r.indexOf(rtt);
    r.splice(i,1, rt);
    return r.join(" ");
}

var replaced = replace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");

document.write(replaced);
```

Comment: yes, I know that. But r.splice() modifies r array. after that r should return new modified array r, and it returns it. But after that when I do r.join(" "), it will not return the string, just existing modified array.  But it will return a string if I declare a new variable  var join = r.join. Why?

Comment: Nope,  `r.splice()` would returns a new array, having modified the contents of `r`. So using `r.join` then will do that you want. Please check the above snippet, which essentially is your code with altered the return statement as I suggested you do so.

Comment: I think I know what is a problem. I thought that join method is similar to array mutators, and that it will modify existing array, but it is wrong. Is that right?

Comment: Exaclty, this is the reason :) !

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `splice()` method changes the original array.

> The `splice()` method adds/removes items to/from an array, and **returns the removed item(s).**

Now, you can simply continue using the old variable instead of a new `var` if the array is still required in the due course of the code.